# AJAX function wont process more than one submission

Tags: jquery, ajax

[This is what it looks like on my page to give you a better visual.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1V2bq.png)This is properly saving the data to the database. It is staying on the page and not refreshing, as desired. 
The only **problem** I am having is when I try to save information twice. After the first save, nothing will save to the database unless I physically hit the page refresh button.

*For example:* I would change the name of an item and click the save button. The new title is properly uploaded to the database. I may then realize there was an error in my title and save it again after fixing it, but the new changes will not save.

```
 <script type="application/javascript">

  $(function() {

  //declaration
   var success = $("#success");


//if the save button is pressed
$(".saveitem_form").submit(function(e){


success.text("Saving.....");
//$("#success").load('admin_editprices.php #success');

var dataString = $(this).serialize();
var action = $(this).attr('action');

  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: action,
    data: dataString,
    success: finish
  });
$('.allproducts').load('admin_editprices.php .allproducts');



 e.preventDefault();
 return false;

});

//if the ajax function was a success
function finish() {


 success.text("Saved.");

   }

  });
</script>
```

Comment: seems you need move `$('.allproducts').load` into `finish` function

Comment: @Grundy I tired that. No change.

Answer (score 0):

Put `$('.allproducts').load('admin_editprices.php .allproducts');` into your `success` function to refresh data after ajax action is completed

I would even recommend to move it into separate function like

```
function loadProducts() {
    $('.allproducts').load('admin_editprices.php .allproducts');
}
function finish() {
    success.text("Saved.");
    loadProducts();
}
```

However, [jQuery Load](http://api.jquery.com/load/) function can cache the results so if you see no changes after ajax update is finished and database value is changed you might need to change loadProducts function to use `ajax` instead of `load`

```
function loadProducts() {
    $.ajax({
        url: "admin_editprices.php",
        cache: false,
        dataType: "html",
        success: function(data) {
            $(".allproducts").html(data);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: I still had the save response. I am only able to use the 'save' button i made once. No other saves are being uploaded unless I refresh the page manually.

Comment: I edited the post, please take a look and let me know if it solves the problem

Comment: That does not seem to be the case. Could it possibly be that my variables are uploading the old values again, instead of the new values?

Comment: I thought you checked the database to be sure it updates, if it doesn't, add cache: false to your ajax update function

Comment: That code actually crashed the page. It submitted and uploaded to the database, but then it froze, started loaded up my header inside of the body and crashed. It was very strange.

Comment: Putting it simply @sef4eg,  I did what you said and the page crashed.

Comment: Weird.. have you checked the database on if it really updates the values?